# ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, database-design, scripting, sqlplus

I am running a script that "creates/replaces" a procedure in a database and then runs the procedure. The code is as below:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT

UNDEFINE g_cust_pwd
UNDEFINE g_db_name

SPOOL 'output'

PROMPT setup_and_run.sql begin

ACCEPT g_db_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter the DB instance: '
ACCEPT g_cust_pwd PROMPT 'Please enter the TEST_SCHEMA schema password: ' HIDE

PROMPT Testing connection

CONNECT TEST_SCHEMA/&&g_cust_pwd@&&g_db_name

WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 

SET DEFINE OFF

PROMPT
PROMPT @procedure_test.prc
PROMPT Creating or Replacing Procedure
@procedure_test.prc

PROMPT
PROMPT procedure_test
PROMPT Running Procedure...
EXEC procedure_test

PROMPT setup_and_run.sql complete

SPOOL OFF

UNDEFINE g_cust_pwd
UNDEFINE g_db_name
/
```

Whenever I run the code above with the correct credentials (double, triple checked these to make sure that this isn't the issue). The code works fine, as expected, the problem occurs whenever I run the code for a second time in the same SQLPlus session it gives a TNS error.

Normally, I would assume that this is merely a TNS names error and the database needs to be added to the list, but it works only once per session (even if I add a disconnect at the end)

Comment: Does it ask for the new database instance name when it runs for the second time? Have you checked that whether the variable `g_db_name` has previous value as you have entered first time? The connect identifier you have supplied couldn't be resolved using tnsname.ora file hence the error.

Comment: It would be better if you could add the exact output of the execution of the script with errors in SQLPLUS.

Answer (score 1):

In line 21:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

But you never re-enable it. When you run the script the 2nd time, substitution variables are not replaced with values provided by the user, because `DEFINE` is still `OFF`. Just add the below to the start of your script, so variables will be used in consecutive runs:

```
SET DEFINE ON
```